# Having issues installing and using npm install -g yo generator-code on macOS Ventura

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, installation, vscode-extensions, yo

I wanted to update my Visual code studio theme I've created when I went to my terminal to update my theme. I put in the words. Yo code is showed an error that it couldn't be installed or found. I have installed the generator a few weeks ago. When I tried to reinstall it it told me to install it as an administrator, I did that when the process is complete I entered the same word. Yo code did not work so I decided to delete it all together, then reinstall it, but it didn't work. I have node installed and MPM I did the procedures correctly, but the generator does not work at all.

I tried reinstalling the generator, through node and NPM both as an administrator, but it did not work at all. I did a lot of research regarding that is shell, but there is no solution that kind of fix that issue I'm having.